# How can I edit my text in python when it's full of special characters?

Tags: python, text-editor

I've been trying to edit a FASTA file in python but it looks like it doesn't understand the input I'm giving for it to replace.

For clarification I have a file called sequence.fasta which is read as text, in it contains wildly variable text, with the same format specified below

IE.

{ "downloadTime": "****************", "downloadTimeStamp": ***********, "genome": "hg38", "chrom": "chr1", "start": ********, "end": *******, "dna": "[DNA SEQUENCE I'M TRYING TO ISOLATE]"}

```
import re;
with open("sequence.fasta", "r") as text:
    text_data = text.readlines()
    for word('{') in text_data:
        result = '>'
    for word(', \"dna\": \"') in text_data:
        result = "\n"
```

I was expecting it to remove the initial "{" in the file and replace it with a ">", and remove the [, "dna": "] and replace it with a line break, leaving two lines only, with the second line being my desires result with a ["] on the end. Please help

Comment: That looks like a JSON file, which means if you were to parse it using the `json` module your life would probably be much easier.

Comment: That said, if you want to isolate the text between [ and ], splitting or using a regex should do the job.

Comment: By the way, `.fasta` files are absolutely not supposed to look like this. The FASTA format looks [completely different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) from what you report you have. You seem to have JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Amongst other ways, you can use string methods.

```
mystring = '{ "downloadTime": "****************", "downloadTimeStamp": ***********, "genome": "hg38", "chrom": "chr1", "start": ********, "end": *******, "dna": "[DNA SEQUENCE IM TRYING TO ISOLATE]"}'
```

- Splitting:

```
dna_sequence = mystring.split('[')[-1].split(']')[0]
```

- Using a regex:

```
import re
dna_sequence = re.findall(r'\[([^\]]*)\]', mystring)[0]
```

Both methods yield the following result:

```
# 'DNA SEQUENCE IM TRYING TO ISOLATE'
```

But, as was mentioned, using a json parser would probably be more relevant.